# Is therea mcu/cpu with an isolated stack (via hardware or compiler)?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

There's the harvard architecture, which isolated the data and code buses. Is there an architecture which also isolated the stack bus in hardware ? or at least some compiler that implements a dual stack - one for return addresses and registers and one for local variables ?

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: One problem with buffer ovrflow is that they give an attacker the option to write into the stack , since the buffer and the stack share a memory bus. I wonder if there's an hardware option that prevents that ability.

Comment: Being able to modify the contents of the stack is essential for multitasking/threading.

Comment: Only local variables not addressed by a constant offset from the stack pointer can introduce such overflow problems. By the way, Itanium's register stack would qualify (the save area is distinct from the local variable stack). Software on Tensilica's XTensa probably saves register contents (which includes the return address) to a separate save area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While most processors have hardware designed to make implementing and using a typical C style stack easy, typically the stack is compiler defined using built in compiler code.

You could implement your own compiler that creates and uses a different style of stack.  In your case you'd be looking to implement two separate stacks, one with input, local, and return variables,and one with call/return locations. You could implement both stacks in a section of memory that can't be executed, nor referred to by pointers in the rest of the code so it can't be altered except by compiler defined function calls and returns. By locating the local variables apart from the call/return stack you'll prevent some types of buffer overflow attacks.

Section 10 of [Basics of Compiler Design](http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/basics_lulu2.pdf)(Free, PDF, 1.6MB) explains function calls and the call stack. If you review that section you'll find that the design of the stack that includes both calls and local variables is very convenient for a number of reasons.  Splitting them up might increase security, but you're slowing the processor and program down by dealing with two stacks.

Except for small special purpose processors, such as the PIC microcontroller, there are no common architectures that implement the concept you're asking about.  However there are a large number of [research processors with various methods of preventing buffer overflow attacks](https://www.google.com/search?q=secure%20buffer%20overflow%20protection%20processor), some of which include concepts similar to yours.

However, even in those processors, it's the compiler's job to deal with the stack.  The processor architecture merely provides additional tools to make protecting the software from attack easier.

You could instead use a language and compiler that is designed in a way that buffer overflow attacks are not possible. Many high level languages today perform array bounds checking on each array access, preventing buffer overflow attacks. This is, largely, a solved problem for many languages and their compilers.

Comment: Many earlier versions of the ARM had no hardware concept of the stack other than various mappable versions of R14.  The `BL` instruction stored R15-4 to R14, and added an immediate value to R15.  Interrupts would switch in alternate partial register sets (which included at minimum their own R14 and R15).  Newer ARM processors do an STRMDB (store multiple, with decrement before) to R13 when an interrupt occurs, but in older ones the fact that R13 was a stack pointer was purely a software convention.

Comment: Yeh, it seems that using the right language might be the best choice. And when using rust the performance loss look reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Some PIC processors have a hardware stack, which consists of 8 fixed registers and could be considered "isolated" from the data bus.

Edit: apparently it's all of them ( http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/04/pic-stack-overflow/ ).

However, you've now added something else to your question: the purpose of preventing buffer overflows. This has different implications. Usually buffer overflows rely on (1) inserting code to be run into a buffer in data memory and (2) overwriting the return address to cause that code to be executed. (1) can be defeated by "no-execute" bits present in some MMUs (this has been available on Intel for a long time but only recently given OS support).

On some platforms attacks can be built entirely by changing the stack without adding any code, using ["return orientated programming"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/return-oriented_programming). Having a distinct stack prevents this from being done, but it does not prevent other forms of data corruption by exceeding a buffer and overwriting some other data memory. It's concievable that you could achieve a useful exploit by changing a bit even if the control flow is not changed.

Comment: Do you know which ones?

Comment: PIC16s at least.

Comment: All 8-bit processors I've ever seen have a separate hardware stack.  On the "mid-range" parts I've used, it's a set of 8 13-bit registers; on lower-range parts, it's a pair of 11-bit registers.  On the upper-level parts, it's a set of IIRC 32 20-bit registers.  Only on the upper level parts can software do anything with the stack other than perform calls and returns [on the other parts, overflowing the stack won't cause any problem if one never does enough returns to use a return address that's been overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

- " Is there an architecture which also isolated the stack bus in hardware ?"
  I have never head of an architecture that has a separate stack *bus*. It is, however, quite common to have separate stack pointers (and stacks) for different purposes, e.g. a supervisor stack and a user stack.
  An (old) example: MC68020 [User's Manual (pdf)](http://rainemu.swishparty.co.uk/html/archive/dev/MC68020UM.pdf)
- "...or at least some compiler that implements a dual stack":
  There is the concept of not using the stack for local variables at all, but allocating local variables in overlayed memory areas.
  Of course this is only possible if the call hierarchy is static (i.e. no recursion and run time dependency of the call hierarchy).
  Example: [C51 Keil C-Compiler](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/961.htm).